# python-pushover error on Vercel deployment

Tags: python, flask, vercel, pushover

I'm trying to deploy a Flask app to Vercel and get this error, which I believe is because of the **python-pushover** package.

Here is the error log which gets generated after I run **vercel --prod** on the terminal.

```
[01:19:33.416] Downloading 523 deployment files...
[01:19:42.856] Looking up build cache...
[01:19:43.125] Build Cache not found
[01:19:43.439] Running "vercel build"
[01:19:44.052] Vercel CLI 25.1.1-canary.7 build (beta) — https://vercel.com/feedback
[01:19:44.211] WARN! Due to `builds` existing in your configuration file, the Build and Development Settings defined in your Project Settings will not apply. Learn More: https://vercel.link/unused-build-settings
[01:19:44.350] Installing required dependencies...
[01:19:48.362] Failed to run "pip3.9 install --disable-pip-version-check --target . --upgrade -r /vercel/path1/requirements.txt"
[01:19:48.424] Error! Command failed: pip3.9 install --disable-pip-version-check --target . --upgrade -r /vercel/path1/requirements.txt
[01:19:48.424]   error: subprocess-exited-with-error
[01:19:48.424]   
[01:19:48.424]   × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
[01:19:48.425]   │ exit code: 1
[01:19:48.425]   ╰─> [1 lines of output]
[01:19:48.425]       error in python-pushover setup command: use_2to3 is invalid.
[01:19:48.425]       [end of output]
[01:19:48.425]   
[01:19:48.425]   note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
[01:19:48.425] error: metadata-generation-failed
[01:19:48.425] 
[01:19:48.425] × Encountered error while generating package metadata.
[01:19:48.426] ╰─> See above for output.
[01:19:48.426] 
[01:19:48.426] note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
[01:19:48.426] hint: See above for details.
[01:19:48.426] 
[01:19:48.428] Collecting python-pushover==0.4
[01:19:48.428]   Downloading python-pushover-0.4.tar.gz (19 kB)
[01:19:48.428]   Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
[01:19:48.428]   Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
[01:19:48.428] 
[01:19:48.535] Error: Command "vercel build" exited with 1
```

I have python3.9 installed in the Pipenv environment.

Has anyone encountered this error before and can provide a solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, You have to check version is support by vercel. I had a similar error, I can solve it fist by checking if I using the venv in python then check if it update.
On Windows the recommended command is:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```